# How can I use PySpark to read an Excel (.xlsx) file from a NAS drive location and load it into Azure Databricks?

Tags: python, excel, azure, pyspark

How to read a excel(.xlsx) file from NAS drive location to azure databricks using pyspark?

Is it even possible ? or any other alternate?
I have linked service in ADF for NAS is it possible to fetch the excel from by connecting to linked service in data  bricks?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you can use the ADLS Azure file share.
And I thank  [CloudIQ](https://www.cloudiqtech.com/integrating-azure-data-lake-storage-with-databricks/).
you can use the Azure storage account File share option.

[image]
You can upload the your excel(.xlsx) file in the File share here (or) you can create a Directory using the Add direcory option and upload file.

[image]

Make sure you have the **Select Role: Storage Blob Data Contributor**

Once you ready uploaded file in the directory you can use browse option to view the files in the Directory.

[image]
Once you have Setup all the above you can login to your databricks workspace.

And use the below commands to connect to your ADLS filse share and access to the Excel(.xlsx) file from databricks

```
spark.conf.set(
"fs.azure.account.key.adlsgen2may15.dfs.core.windows.net",
"<Storageaccount access key>"
)

spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.adlsgen2may15.blob.core.windows.net",
  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
)
```

[image]
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://adlsgen2may15.blob.core.windows.net/may15fileshare")

Use the above commands to connect your fileshare with Azure databricks
Or
If you have more no of file in the NAS.
You can use the Copy activity in ADF to move the file from the NAS to the Storage account.
And use the above code that helps you step up connection to your storage account and Databricks.

The Pipeline Flow can help you pick the files from the storage and also can help automate the process through the triggers in ADF.

Comment: we cannot upload the file on storage. We have a encryption algo where we need to first encrypt the data in file then manupulate.